# How can I apply this header/footer margin between UITableViewCells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This code creates a margin at the top and bottom of the `UITableView`. How can I modify it to do the same but between each individual `UITableViewCell`?

```
// set header height
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

// set header colour
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    return headerView;
}

// set footer height
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

// set footer colour
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    return headerView;
}
```

If successful, I'd also like to be able to add similar left and right margins if possible.

Comment: A section for each Cell could be what you're looking for. For the left/right margin : Custom Cells could do it.

Comment: How would I modify the code for that? My attempts in that direction have so far been unsuccessful...

Comment: You have a method that returns the number of rows, and another one that return the number of sections. Reverses theses numbers, and modify the cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Why would reversing the number of rows (which is dynamic) and sections affect this?

Comment: Frankly, it sounds like you should just make your own custom cell with this particular layout...

Comment: @Sebastian: Because is the easiest way. You want to had a footer view and an header view to each UITableViewCell, and the method you're using a for sections, not for row.

Comment: I see, and how would I add left and right margins?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Use an extra Background `UIView` with top, left. bottom and right margin.[red background view in the picture]. Add all other subViews on this view.